# Did not find value in MATCH evaluation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My formula is supposed to grab numbers ranging from the cell H and then output numbers in cell I. However, I am getting an N/A error for some reason.

```
=INDEX({7,10,15,30,55,70,80,100,110},MATCH(H1,{0,4,8,15,25,35,45,55,65,70}))
```

Is there an error with the formula created?

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you on a european sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the formula to this?
It looks like column H is being pasted/imported as text rather than number values. the "1*" will force it to a number if possible based on your locale.

```
=INDEX({7,10,15,30,55,70,80,100,110},MATCH(1*H1,{0,4,8,15,25,35,45,55,65,70}))
```

Alternatively, Try just formatting the Column as Format>Number>Automatic

Comment: In my case, I needed the `TO_TEXT(H1)` function.